# Bash, output from file between 2 patterns, but with variables and asterisks

Tags: sed

**Issue**

I need select all between 2 patterns in file, but with variables and with `*` as wildcards.

Example (something like that).

```
myscript var1 var2 var3
```

Script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | sed -n "/*$2*$3/,/## end of string ##/p"
```

It is not working as I expect, because `*` is not get as `anything`. `*` should be anything between variables. Example of file (`$1`)is for example this.

```
## First line, first variable is var2, and second variable is var3. Information text.
Some text
to display.
## end of string ##
```

Am I clear? Thanks.

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-29-lowlatency #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 12 14:13:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit**

For example, input file `in.txt` is here.

```
## bash, file, csv, show duplicate lines by column, uniq -d is don't repeat
cut -d'|' -f1,2,3 dbdump.csv | sort -k3 -t'|' | uniq -D
cut -d '|' -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 dbdump.csv | uniq -d | grep -Ff - dbdump.csv

## bash, folders, rename string in directory name
find -name "* *" -type d | rename 's/ /_/g'

## bash, files, remove all files instead *.jpg (or mp4)
find . -type f -not -name '*.jpg' -delete
rm -v !(*.jpg|*.mp4)

## bash, files, find files and multiple rename
find ./ -type f -readable -writable -exec sed -i "s/OLD/NEW/g" {} \;
```

Code of script `myscript.sh` is here.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | sed -n "/*$2*$3*$4/,/##/p"
```

Example of using `myscript.sh`.

```
myscript.sh in.txt bash file rem
```

Output from the script should be this (get file, display output from pattern1 - line, where is $2 (bash), $3 (file), and $4 (rem) on one line, divided by anything, simply `something $2 something $3 something $4 something`, to pattern2 `## end of string ##`. So only this.

```
## bash, files, remove all files instead *.jpg (or mp4)
find . -type f -not -name '*.jpg' -delete
rm -v !(*.jpg|*.mp4)
```

Comment: Please add the desired output for your (I guess input?) example.

Comment: @dessert Shebang inserted. :)

Comment: If you’re going to print the whole line anyway, what’s the point in selecting stuff between $2 and $3?

Comment: To elaborate on what steeldriver wrote about regex: To match any number of any character in a `sed` expression you need to use `.*`, e.g.: `/.*$2.*$3/`

Comment: @dessert Yes! Thanks. And last question, how can I remove last line for every cycle? Some `$d` option to `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, this works.

Script `myscript.sh`.

```
sed -n '/## '$1'.* '$2'.* '$3'/,/^$/p' in.txt
```

`^$`, for removing last line of cycle.

Example of use.

```
myscript.sh bash fil rem
```

Output (exactly what i need).

```
## bash, files, remove string from all files
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file/000/}"; done

## bash, files, remove all files from folder except defined
find [path] -type f -not -name 'textfile.txt' -not -name 'backup.tar.gz' -delete

## bash, files, remove all files instead *.jpg (or mp4)
find . -type f -not -name '*.jpg' -delete
rm -v !(*.jpg|*.mp4)
```

Thanks to all for cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to output multi-line blocks of text, I'd suggest `awk` rather than `sed`

For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

infile="$1"
shift

# construct a regular expression string from the remaining positional parameters
printf -v re -- '.*%s' "$@"
# NB unexpected things may happen if parameters contain regex-special characters

awk -v re="$re" '/##/ {p=0} $0 ~ re {p=1} p' "$infile"
```

If your input is really split into whitespace-delineated blocks, it might be cleaner to use awk in *paragraph mode*, treating each line as a field:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

infile="$1"
shift

# construct a regular expression string from the remaining positional parameters
printf -v re -- '.*%s' "$@"
# NB unexpected things may happen if parameters contain regex-special characters

awk -v RS= -v re="$re" -F'\n' '$1 ~ re' "$infile"
```